# ReactJS restrict Textfield to numeric with 2 decimal places

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to restrict to 2 decimal places but for some reason, normal regEx solutions are not working 
This ensures only numbers are entered with a decimal but I need 2 decimal places only
     { e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') }}   />

Answer (score 0):

You can just validate it within the `onChange()` of the `TextFIeld`.
YOu can split the result String with `.` operator and check if the 2nd String has a length greater than 2 then don't use `setState({})`

```
onChange={(e)=>{
    const value = e.target.value;
    const arr = value.split('.');
    if(arr.length <= 2 && arr[1].length <= 2 ) 
     setState({
       value
     });
}}
```

Comment: Hi I am not using state

Comment: Watch out with this one, not all cultures use a decimal point for a value separator, e.g dutch uses ,